# Explanation of Tomcat GC log statements

Tags: tomcat, logging, garbage-collection

Here is a statement from my catalina.out, generated by my tomcat server :

1885.855: [GC [PSYoungGen: 742996K->64359K(761472K)] 2509583K->1832973K(4116928K), 0.1453610 secs] [Times: user=0.31 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs]

Could someone explain the meaning of various numbers in here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The break-up of the line is as followd:

`1885.85` - this in seconds is the amount of time the JVM has been running, so around 31 minutes or so in your case at which point the GC took place.

`[GC` - states a GC occured at this point in time. This is a Partial GC, sometimes it will show `Full GC`

Now, the Total Heap available for the JVM = Young + Old

`[PSYoungGen:742996K->64359K(761472K)` - represents the Parallel Scavenging Collector in the Young generation (which is one of the many types of GC collectors available in the JVM).

The memory freed by GC is always of the pattern

```
x->y(z)
```

> x is the initial memory before GC, y is
>   the memory after GC, z is the total
>   memory allowed for that area in the
>   JVM

so in your example, 
`742996K->64359K(761472K)` - the total Young size is 761Mb, and when it reached 742 Mb a collection took place, and it cleared down to 64.3Mb
i.e. it cleared up 678 Mb

```
2509583K->1832973K(4116928K)
```

Here the total heap memory is represented. 
So out of a total possible heap of 4.1 Gb, when the GC took place, it had filled 2.5 Gb and it has come down to 1.83 Gb - again the same 678 Mb is what got cleared.

```
0.1453610 secs]
```

This entire operation took 0.1453610 seconds

```
[Times: user=0.31 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs]
```

shows the break-up of [user, system and real times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) taken.

This is just one line - you would be looking for a pattern esp one that says `Full GC` in it
And use a log analyzer like [GCViewer](http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/06/slow-weblogic-part-6-jvm-heap-analysis.html) for showing you throughput and other good stuff.

Also read the [docs from Sun](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html) to get the basics.

**Further reading:**

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/08/charting-jvm-garbage-collection.html

[Java Garbage Collection Log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895444/java-garbage-collection-log-messages)

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/example.html and http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the break-up of user, system and real times taken? The unix interpretation is fine but I don't understand how these times matter in the context of GC.