# Is GC_FOR_ALLOC more "serious" when investigating memory usage?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I'm currently investigating garbage collection problems with my Android app, and I'm curious to know if GC_FOR_ALLOC is indicative of a bigger problem than other GC messages, such as GC_CONCURRENT.

From my understanding, GC_CONCURRENT is doing what the garbage collector should do. The heap has reached a particular limit, better go clean up memory.

GC_FOR_ALLOC suggests to me something more serious is happening if I'm trying to create an object and there's no memory left to do it.

Is there a priority or "seriousness" level for the GC messages?

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895444/java-garbage-collection-log-messages ? the links referred in the accepted answer may help you

Comment: @kommradHomer Thanks for the response but I don't think that applies here since it is the dalvik virtual machine that would be doing the GC sweep. I still found the link to be an informative, if dense, read.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In a sense, `GC_FOR_ALLOC` is more serious than `GC_CONCURRENT`, because `GC_FOR_ALLOC` means there were not enough free memory to fulfill an allocation request, so a garbage collection was necessary, whereas `GC_CONCURRENT` just means that the GC felt like running, typically because the amount of free memory became lower than a certain threshold after an allocation.

A `GC_FOR_ALLOC` is by itself not a sign of a problem in your application however:

- Android applications start with a small heap which grows (up to a point) when applications require more and more memory, and a `GC_FOR_ALLOC` is done before increasing the size of the heap. In this case `GC_FOR_ALLOC` is perfectly normal.
- If you allocate memory faster than the concurrent GC has time to free it up, `GC_FOR_ALLOC` is inevitable. And there's nothing inherently wrong with allocating memory faster than the concurrent GC can free up memory.

A more serious type of GC on Android is `GC_BEFORE_OOM`, which is performed when an allocation request fails even after `GC_FOR_ALLOC` and when the application heap has grown as big as it is allowed to be. When this happen, as a last resort, Dalvik will try to release SoftReferences as well, before doing a final attempt at allocating memory and if that fails throw an OutOfMemory exception.

If you're curious to look at the code for this logic, it is in `tryMalloc()` in [dalvik.git/vm/alloc/Heap.cpp](http://git.omapzoom.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=vm/alloc/Heap.cpp;h=9eee817e5e5cc1115041c5548214292a7f6e1090;hb=HEAD)

Anyway, if you don't mind, I doubt that looking at logcat output is the most efficient way to debug your garbage collection problems. I don't know what specific problem you are having, but have you looked into tools such as the Allocation Tracker in DDMS and analyzing heap dumps with the help of the `hprof-conv` tool? (See http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html for example to get started.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. My app has been out in the wild for a while now and we're working on doing some fine tuning to it. One of the big overheads was the GC running up to 30 times within a window of 4 seconds. It just seemed excessive really. With some optimisation, GC runs 6 times now - but FOR_ALLOC is the only call that is being made. But that makes sense now.