# Android Java - Rotate Bitmap causes GC_FOR_ALLOC

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation

I'm trying to set a bitmap's rotation using a matrix but I am having some trouble here.

Does anyone know how to rotate a bitmap?? I am so confused why this would give out of memory errors.  My code is plain and simple:

```
thisRotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(
            (fingery1 - thisRectf.centerY()),
            (fingerx1 - thisRectf.centerX()))));
matrix.setRotate(thisRotation, thisRectf.centerX(),
            thisRectf.centerY());
Bitmap.createBitmap(thisBitmap, 0, 0, thisBitmap.getWidth(), 
                         thisBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

I have used google and apparently this is not an easy fix?  My image is very small (9 kb) and i've tried lowering it to 900 bytes but it still causes gc.

Comment: Unless you're getting actual OutOfMemoryException or having performance issues due to the gc I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Look at my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128346/getting-rotation-from-exifinterface-always-returns-0/24219714#24219714

Comment: Please check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260761/is-gc-for-alloc-more-serious-when-investigating-memory-usage relates or answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a custom view, and in my onDraw method, I used

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRectf, dstRectf, paint);
```

to draw my bitmap, but I should have been using

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```