# Not able to print GC details

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to print the GC details for a test program in eclipse.I want to set it only for my program so I went to Run>Run Configurations and in VM arguments gave this:

```
-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M    –XX:+PrintGCDetails  –XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

However when I do this and run my program I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: –XX:+PrintGCDetails
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: –XX:+PrintGCDetails
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

What am I doing wrong in passing the arguments.

Comment: Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895444/java-garbage-collection-log-messages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What should tip you off is the error message `NoClassDefFoundError: –XX:+PrintGCDetails` - the JVM isn't trying to parse it as an option but a class...

Then, look at the dashes before `-Xms1024M` and `–XX:+PrintGCDetails` / `–XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` - they're different!

Replace the latter ones with the former (ie. "real" dashes/minus-sign) and you're good to go.

Cheers,