# Allocation failure in Java

Tags: java, memory-management

I have a method which hits DB and fetches lot of records into memory for processing. After I fetch the records and before I start processing, I get the following log message. What does it mean ?

```
164575.034: [GC (Allocation Failure)  4937664K->3619624K(5602816K), 0.0338580 secs]
```

Options:

```
java.opts=-d64 -Xmx8g -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

Comment: It looks like it means it started a GC due to an allocation failure i.e. it ran out of space in the current generation. Which platform are you using?

Comment: What are your JVM arguments ?

Comment: java.opts=-d64 -Xmx8g -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC

Comment: Does batching of fetching & processing records help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Garbage Collection Log messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895444/java-garbage-collection-log-messages)

Comment: This message says “Allocation Failure”. Not “GC failure”. Your program tried to allocate memory. This failed because there was too little memory available, so the garbage collector ran, and it freed some memory.

Comment: You can increase the amount of memory to the JVM with the -Xms<size> and -Xmx<size> switches. But maybe you need to fetch the records in smaller batches instead? Are you keeping any references to objects unnecessarily?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342736/java-gc-allocation-failure

Answer (score 12):

It just basically tells you that it had to run GC to allocate additional memory, it does not fit in memory otherwise. So it is just a reason for GC.