# Allocation Failure of GC while restarting Tomcat 'apache-tomcat-8.0.33' with 'jdk 1.8'

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

I have a webapp using `JDK1.6` and `Tomcat 6`. After I set the webapp to use `apache-tomcat-8.0.33` and `jdk1.8`, I stop Tomcat and start it again. I see an error in log file as:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_05-b13), built on Mar 18 2014 00:29:27 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
>   Memory: 4k page, physical 32960008k(1705688k free), swap 4095992k(9328k free)
>
> CommandLine flags: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:InitialHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2097152000 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
>
> 0.299: [GC (Allocation Failure)  512K->384K(1048064K), 0.0023630 secs]
>   0.462: [GC (Allocation Failure)  896K->664K(1048064K), 0.0024930 secs]

What may be the problem?

Comment: Although it sounds alarming "Allocation Failure" isn't necessarily an error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342736/java-gc-allocation-failure

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two reasons for these errors with tomcat. 
 1. You aren't allocating enough memory. 
 2. You are allocating too much memory.

I would wager #2.

I might be misreading this:

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 32960008k(1705688k free)
```

But that seems to indicate that you have 1.7GB of available memory. Your heap is taking 1GB initially, with a maximum of 2GB. That doesn't leave a whole lot of available memory.

Unless you really need 1GB heap space, you should reduce that significantly, as well as the maximum heap size.