# "GC (Allocation Failure)" in Cloud Dataflow logs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The logs for my Cloud Dataflow job contain multiple messages of the form:

> [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 72352K->160K(71168K)]
>   120584K->48392K(158720K), 0.0022739 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00,
>   real=0.00 secs]

What does this mean?  What should I do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Allocation Failure" message is a completely normal part of Java memory management; it just means the JVM has run out of memory and needs to trigger a GC.  Unless there is already a reason to suspect memory problems, the "Java GC" log is generally not worth looking at for Dataflow pipelines.

Please see [Java GC (Allocation Failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342736/java-gc-allocation-failure) for additional information.