# Get Notified when a JAVA GC is happening

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I was looking if there's a way to check the JVM or if the JVM may notify a process when a GC is currently taking place.
Is it possible developing an agent with JVMTI? or what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895444/java-garbage-collection-log-messages

Comment: In modern JVMs, garbage collection happens concurrently in the background. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to implement a GC Scout, to block my current AS when GC is happening

Comment: The other question explains how to get something logged, but this question is asking how to be notified.  I think there's an MBean notification sent when a GC has completed, but I don't know if there's one when a GC is starting.

Comment: It says "check the JVM or the JVM may notify the process", which seems to indicate it's a separate process that wants this information.  Parsing the log messages seems adequate for that use case.  (If you do find out about the MBean, you could self-answer another question.)