# Solr ping taking time during full import

Tags: apache, solr, solrj, solr4

I have Solr application with 6 cores.I am facing some weird problem.Ping request some times takes more than 5 minutes to respond when full import is running for one of the cores(We have one core which is designed to run full import every hour).90% of the time i get response immediately but only 10% of the time it fails.

Please help me to debug this problem.This problem is happening only in our production machines.So I dont have options to run anything on it.I tried to simulate problem in local nevironment.But not happening.

My ping handler's config as below

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
 <lst name="invariants">
   <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
 </lst>
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">all</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the GC information from Java? It might be stuck doing GC. See [Java Garbage Collection Log Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895444/java-garbage-collection-log-messages).

Comment: Yes,Its a good point.I will try it.But one this is if there was GC running then I should not see any log messages for that period right?