# Ensuring adequate java heap size

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory, introscope

Is there any way to ensure adequate heap size from current performance of garbage collection?

In std_server0.o00 file, in the end it says like this.

> Heap  par new generation reserved 698368K, committed 698368K, used
>   111483K eden space 349184K, 21% used from space 174592K, 20％ used to
>   space 174592K, 0% used concurrent mark-sweep generation reserved
>   3495936k, committed 3495936K, used 1615621k concurrent mark-sweep perm
>   gen reserved 1048576k, committed 1048576k, used 242435k

from above log could it be said that I have set my maximum heap size too big?

Even not from here, how do you decide whether you set your maximum heap size too big or not?

If I see on OS level, with ps aux | grep PID of Wily Introscope, 
the VSS is 15218952KB, and the RSS is 10424268KB

I am using CA Introscope for SAP application (Wily Introscope). My boss wants to know adequate size for this app. I am new to Java heap.

Any ideas on where to look?

Previously, we had OutOfMemory error and also hanging(frequent stopping) of the application. Thus we changed the heap size to set to 13GB!! it pretty huge i think.
Also we set both -Xms and -Xmx to same size to avoid hanging.

Any reply or advice or anything would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of SAP application is this and at what SAP Java system + host is it deployed? The appropriate heap size is a combination of OS, number of users and application design.

Comment: Hello Michael!  It is Wily Introscope Enterprise Manager on SAP Solution Manager 7.1 SP 12. (Linux 64bit). Number of managed systems by SAP Solution Manager is over 130. But the ones connected to Wily Introscope is about 80 ( This number comes from the Wily Introscope WebView Investigator tab). Customer will not use this application. This one is for getting metric information of the managed systems and analyzing it (but tbh we are not getting full use of it!).

Comment: ABAP+JAVA dual stack!

Comment: Normally, you should be fine with a heap of 4 GB on the server. If I remember correctly, you should run Wily EM on a client PC where the analysis is done; not requiring a large heap on the server? 13 GB is huge but so are 80 systems in Wily.

Comment: Besides application-specific adjustments general GC tuning requires [GC logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/895444/1362755).